# tcl sort a file

Tags: tcl

I have a directory which has multiple files by the name *MIS. Now these files contain repeated lines. 
I need to read all files in the directory named VIA having name *_MIS & update the file after removing the repeated lines(need to do sort -u). Need to use TCL

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing this in pure Tcl, you should split the task into two pieces: a part to sort a file (which will make a nice procedure) and a part that sorts all the relevant files in a directory:

```
proc sort_file {filename} {
    # Read the file
    set f [open $filename]
    set data [read $f]
    close $f

    # Sort the lines, removing dupes
    set lines [split $data "\n"]
    set sorted_uniques [lsort -unique $lines]
    set data [join $sorted_uniques "\n"]

    # Write the file
    set f [open $filename w]
    puts $f $data
    close $f
}

# Now process all the relevant files; the -directory option is a convenient way
# to specify which directory to do the searching in.
foreach filename [glob -directory VIA *_MIS] {
    sort_file $filename
}
```

Key parts of the solution: [`lsort -unique`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lsort.htm#M16) and [`foreach`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/foreach.htm)/[`glob`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/glob.htm).

Comment: Note that the general pattern is the same in Roman's answer; iterate over filenames that match, sorting/uniquifying each one. The only significant difference is that he uses an external program for the inner part of the task.

Comment: Use `-nonewline` with `read` or you'll get a false, empty list element at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following

```
set dir_path path_to_directory_contains_MIS_files
set files_list [glob -directory $dir_path *_MIS]
foreach mis_file $files_list {
    if {[catch {exec sort -u $mis_file -o $mis_file} result]} {
        puts "ERROR: $result"
    } 
}
```