# TCL sort a file mathematically

Tags: tcl

I have a file which has multiple lines like :-

```
A B A 10 20

A B A 10 20

C D A 10 15

A B Q 15 20

A B A 35 45

A B A 15 20

C D A 10 15

A B A 20 25

.

.

.

A A A x1 y1
```

The first three fileds are some text patterns.

Now I want to write a program in TCL which does BOTH of the following:-

1. Does a unique sort "sort -u" for the file & reoves the repeated lines & dumps the O/P in new file.
2. For case where 1st three field is same dump only those lines where the numbers are greater than 10 from each other.

For eg the O/P of above file satisfying both conditions will be:-

```
A B A 10 20

A B A 35 45

C D A 10 15

A B Q 15 20
```

The order of lines is not important in file.

---

```
##Changed the program
set input [open "data.txt" "r"]

set content [read $input]

set lines [lsort -unique [split $content "\n"]]

set keylist ""

set valuelist ""


foreach line $lines {

    if {$line == ""} { continue }
    set data [split $line " "]
    set key [join [lrange $data 0 2] "_"]
    set index [lsearch $keylist $key]

    if {$index != -1} {
        set value [lindex $valuelist $index]

        set diff_a [expr [lindex $data 3] - [lindex $value 0]]
        set diff_b [expr [lindex $data 4] - [lindex $value 1]]

        if {$diff_a > 10 && $diff_b > 10 } {
            puts $line
        }

       set a [ lreplace valuelist $index $index [lrange $data 3 4]]

      set valuelist $a

    } else {
        lappend keylist $key
        lappend valuelist [lrange $data 3 4]
        puts $line
    }
}
```

Comment: look on this [need to do sort -u. Need to use TCL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215600/tcl-sort-a-file), it helps you with the part (1)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a smart solution, but works.

```
set input [open "data.txt" "r"]
set content [read $input]
set lines [lsort -unique [split $content "\n"]]
set keylist ""
set valuelist ""

foreach line $lines {
    if {$line == ""} { continue }
    set data [split $line " "]
    set key [join [lrange $data 0 2] "_"]
    set index [lsearch $keylist $key]

    if {$index != -1} {
        set value [lindex $valuelist $index]

        set diff_a [expr [lindex $data 3] - [lindex $value 0]]
        set diff_b [expr [lindex $data 4] - [lindex $value 1]]

        if {$diff_a > 10 && $diff_b > 10 } {
            puts $line
        }

        set valuelist [lreplace valuelist $index $index [lrange $data 3 4]]
    } else {
        lappend keylist $key
        lappend valuelist [lrange $data 3 4]
        puts $line
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A B A 10 20
A B A 35 45
A B Q 15 20
C D A 10 15
```

Comment: sorry..let me clarify myself.. I want to do a search between different lines ie since "A B A 10 20" so we should only dump a line where "A B A x y" where x & y are > 20 & 30 respectively. so the mathematical search is not in the same line but across the lines.

Comment: I made some modifications to better match you question

Comment: what is the equivalent command for dict for tcl 8.4 or before. "dict" i ssupported from tcl 8.5 onwards. Please modify the script for TCL 8.4

Comment: please anyone help respond. Im stuck

Comment: this is giving me a different output. We see the x same in some lines in O/P

Comment: the "$value" value is not chnaging.

Comment: the issue is that TCL does not properly execute the "lreplace valuelist $index $index [lrange $data 3 4]". If we set it to a variable and then set the valuelist again then it works fine

Comment: i'm sorry i forgot to set `valuelist` after `lreplace` in the example above, but glad you finally solved your problem

Comment: i have one more question how do I take the absolute value of the diff_a & diff_b. Please tell me what is the modulus function of tcl in 8.4